# NEGATION INNER JOIN with WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Why the sql code below ignores

> WHERE r.tt_schedules_id = '105'

in

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.load_date, u.url
FROM tt_results r
INNER JOIN url_lp u
ON u.lp_id <> r.lp_id
INNER JOIN tt_schedules s
ON s.tt_schedules_id = r.tt_schedules_id
WHERE r.tt_schedules_id = '105'
AND (DATE(NOW()) - DATE(r.load_date) <= 7)
```

?

Basically, it returns everything with any

> tt_schedules_id

There are 5 tables:

> url_lp, tt_results (table having foreign keys in url_lp, tt_schedules and
>   tt_tags), tt_schedules, tt_tags(not used) and tt_schedules_url_lp_hub

If you draw the scheme on the paper you should be clear.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this:  INNER JOIN url_lp u ON u.lp_id <> r.lp_id.  You should use a Left Outer Join or a Subquery with NOT IN.

Comment: The query certainly doesn't ignore `WHERE r.tt_schedules_id = '105'`. Put r.tt_schedules_id in your select clause and you will see it's 105. SQLDBA is right, though. Your join ("join the result with every URL that has nothing to do with it") looks suspicious and may be the reason for your confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:

```
SELECT u.url FROM url_lp u
INNER JOIN tt_schedules_url_lp_hub hub
ON hub.lp_id = u.lp_id
INNER JOIN tt_schedules s
ON hub.tt_schedules_id = s.tt_schedules_id
WHERE s.tt_schedules_id = '105'
AND u.lp_id NOT IN 
(SELECT r.lp_id FROM tt_results r WHERE r.tt_schedules_id = '105')
```

Cheers.